# How to change the touch icon in a Drupal 7, Omega sub theme

Tags: android, mobile, drupal, configuration

My Drupal 7 Omega sub theme is showing the default Omega icon. I can see in the theme settings that the option for Apple touch icons is checked, but I can not see where to change this.

I have updated the favicon and the logo successfully, but I can not work out where to change the touch icons for mobile.

Answer (score 1):

I eventually worked out that I could simply recreate the touch icons within the sub theme with the same names as that in the parent theme